# Obtener nombre de las variables además del valor

Tags: java, variables, switch

Mi programa corre sin problema y me da los resultados esperados, sin embargo, al final, en el bloque donde se hace el cálculo de mayor y menor cantidad de infectados, me gustaría saber como puedo obtener, además del número, el nombre del municipio que contiene el mayor y menor número de infectados ya que con lo que sé solo puedo obtener las cantidades de dichas variables. el detalle solo es en el **case 4 y 5** del switch, ya que no he podido encontrar la manera de hacerlo, he visto que algunos obtienen el nombre con getname(), pero la verdad no sé o no entiendo como aplicarlo a mi código. Comparto mi código:

```
package menu_quintana_roo;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Menu_Quintana_Roo {

    public static void main(String[] args){
       //Declaración de variables
    byte opcion;
    int    infCozumel=0, infIsla=0, infCarmen=0, infCancun=0, counter = 0, infectados=0,
           semaforoQR=0, menor= 0;
    String municipio = "";
    
    
    //Creación del Menú
    
    do{
        opcion = Byte.parseByte(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
        "MENÚ PRINCIPAL\n"
    +   "¿QUE ES LO QUE DESEA HACER?:\n"
    +   "1. Registro número de infectados por municipio\n"
    +   "2. Saber el color de semáforo en el que se encuentra Quintana Roo\n"
    +   "3. Conocer media de contagios a nivel estatal\n"
    +   "4. Municipio con mas contagios\n"
    +   "5. Municipio con menos contagios\n"
    +   "6. Salir\n"
    ));
         //Sentencia de casos para opciones del menú
       switch(opcion){
           case 1:
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Bienvenido al registro de infectados por municipio, por favor conteste lo siguiente:"); //Métodos para solicitar datos
               while (counter < 4){ // Inicio del contador
                   counter = counter +1;
                   infectados = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Indica el número de infectados a registrar")); //Registro de # infectados por municipio
                   municipio=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "A que municipio pertenecen esos " + infectados + " infectados?"); //asignacion de infectados a municipios.
                        if(municipio.equalsIgnoreCase("cozumel")){
                            infCozumel = infCozumel + infectados ;
                        }else if(municipio.equalsIgnoreCase("isla mujeres")){
                            infIsla = infIsla + infectados;
                        }else if(municipio.equalsIgnoreCase("Playa del carmen")){
                            infCarmen = infCarmen + infectados;
                        }else if(municipio.equalsIgnoreCase("cancun")){
                            infCancun = infCancun + infectados;                        
                        }

               } //Fin del Counter
               
              break;
           case 2:
                 semaforoQR = infCozumel + infCarmen + infIsla + infCancun; //selección de color de semáforo de acuerdo a cantidad de infectados totales.
                            if(semaforoQR >= 75){
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Con un total de " +semaforoQR + " infectados, Quintana Roo se encuentra en Semáforo Rojo");
                            }else if(semaforoQR >= 51 && semaforoQR <= 75 ){
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Con un total de " +semaforoQR + " infectados, Quintana Roo se encuentra en Semáforo naranja");
                            }else if(semaforoQR >= 26 && semaforoQR <= 50 ){
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Con un total de " +semaforoQR + " infectados, Quintana Roo se encuentra en Semáforo amarillo");
                            }else if(semaforoQR >= 0 && semaforoQR <= 25 ){
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Con un total de " +semaforoQR + " infectados, Quintana Roo se encuentra en Semáforo verde");    
                            }    
              break;
           case 3:
                 double media;
                    media = semaforoQR / 4;// Media de infectados a nivel por municipio
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La media de infectados en el estado es de "+ media + " personas infectadas por municipio");     
              break;
           case 4: //Municipio con más infectados
               int[] lista = new int[4];
               int mayor = lista[0];
                    lista[0] = infCozumel;
                    lista[1] = infIsla;
                    lista[2] = infCarmen;
                    lista[3] = infCancun;
               for(int i=0; i < lista.length; i++){
                     if(lista[i] > mayor){
                            mayor = lista[i];                      
                     }
                 }
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El municipio con más infectados es " + mayor);
              break;
           case 5:  //Municipio con menos infectados
               int[] lista1 = new int[4];
                    lista1[0] = infCozumel;
                    lista1[1] = infIsla;
                    lista1[2] = infCarmen;
                    lista1[3] = infCancun;
                    mayor = menor = lista1[0];
                for(int i=0; i < lista1.length; i++){
                     if(lista1[0] < menor){
                            menor = lista1[i];                      
                     }
                     
                }  
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El municipio con menos infectados es " + mayor); 
              break;
           case 6: //Salida.
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Gracias por utilizar el sistema de informacion estatal de Quintana Roo");
              break;    
           default:
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Opción Inválida, por favor, seleccione una opción entre 1 y 6."); //Excepción en caso de seleccionar una opción no registrada.
              break;
   
       } //Fin del switch
    }while(opcion!=6);
    System.exit(0);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: En que momento declaras el nombre o datos de los municipios? Por lo qu veo, estos son los que inician con inf no ?¿

Comment: @Excorpion correcto, los que comienzan con inf son los nombres de los municipios.

Comment: Lo que podrías tener sería un Array que tuviera los datos de cada municipio. Ya sean estos nombre, valor, o lo que tu quieras obtener de cada municipio. Hasta ahora veo que necesitas el nombre, y un valor (que no se que significa), necesitas más datos de ellos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se me ocurre que hagas una matriz bidimensional, luego que arregles, uses una variable para capturar cual de ellas es el mayor, suponiendo que `infNombre` es un valor entero podrías intentarlo de la siguiente manera.

Simplemente agregue el valor de los municipios, luego con `bandera` capturo el índice y lo mando dentro de la `consola`, ya tu usarías el `JOptionPanel`

```
String[][] lista = new String[4][2];
lista[0][0] = infCozumel+"";    lista[0][1]="infCozumel";
lista[1][0] = infIsla+"";       lista[1][1]="infIsla";
lista[2][0] = infCarmen+"";     lista[2][1]="infCarmen";
lista[3][0] = infCancun+"";     lista[3][1]="infCancun";
int mayor = Integer.parseInt(lista[0][0]);
int bandera = 0;
for(int i=0; i < lista.length; i++){
            if(Integer.parseInt(lista[i][0]) > mayor){
            mayor = Integer.parseInt(lista[i][0]);   
            bandera = i;
            }
        }

System.out.println("El municipio con más infectados es: " + lista[bandera][1]);
System.out.println("Cantidad infectados es: " + mayor);
```

Comment: Gracias @felipe, apenas estoy tratando de entender arreglos unidimensionales jeje, soy  nuevo en esto de programación Java, tratare de leer un poco más y comprender los bidimensionales.

Answer (score 0):

te recomiendo que en vez de una lista trabajes con un HasMap, te adjuntare un  código para resolver tu caso 4.

```
           case 4: //Municipio con más infectados
           Map<String,Integer>  mapa = new HashMap <>();
           //asignamos los valores por cada municipio
           mapa.put("cozumel", infCozumel);
           mapa.put("isla mujeres", infIsla);
           mapa.put("Playa del carmen", infCarmen);
           mapa.put("cancun", infCancun);  
           //obtenemos el valorn maximo del mapa
           int mayor = (Collections.max(mapa.values())); 
           //iteramos el mapa hasta encontrar la key(nombre) del valor maximo
           for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : mapa.entrySet()) {  
           if (entry.getValue()==mayor) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El municipio con más infectados es " + entry.getKey());
           }
```

Te recomiendo también que leas esta documentación.  [Map<K,V> java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)